# Жительница Запорожья

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он - запорожец, а она? Запорожка? Запороженка? Как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запорож**а**нка. 
Форма кажется необычной, но в сравнении, скажем, с "итальянка", "дончанка" и проч. не выглядит столь уж странной.

Answer (score 3):

Жительница Запорожья - *запорожАнка*. (Словарь-справочник "Русские названия жителей" Городецкой и Левашова)
Для некоторых топонимов в русском языке нет (или образуется с затруднениями) соответствующего устоявшегося этнохоронима (чаще всего этнохоронима женского рода). В этом случае жители той или иной местности называются описательно, например *жительница Запорожья*.

Comment: В "запорожанке" нет ничего затруднительного. Затруднения обычно касаются только иностранных названий типа Нью-Йорка.

Comment: Если бы не было затруднений, не задавали бы таких вопросов. И не только иностранных названий они касаются. Как бы вы назвали жительницу Воронежа?

Comment: Воронежка. Какие проблемы?
У меня несколько знакомых оттуда, они себя только так называют.
Кажется, раньше был докгой вариант, воронежанка, кажется, если не воронежчанка. Но тут я без гугла не скажу.

Я вполне серьёзно насчет иностранных названий. Для своего, родного язык всегда найдёт подходящий вариант.  Во всяком случае я не знаю исключений для сколько-нибудь известных топонимов и этнохоронимов.

Comment: Ни в одном словаре нет слов воронежка, воронежанка, воронежчанка (в то время как запорожанка есть). Давайте не будем забывать о нормативности. Как разговорные варианты - сколько угодно. Но пока ни один словарь не зафиксировал этих названий.

Comment: Затруднения возникают обычно при образовании названий женского рода от этнохоронимов мужского рода с суффиксом -ец. Во всех остальных случаях все довольно просто.

Comment: >Затруднения возникают обычно при образовании названий женского рода от этнохоронимов мужского рода с суффиксом -ец. Во всех остальных случаях все довольно просто.   

Никогда об этом не задумывался. Но даже если так, не вижу в этом каких-то глубинных причин. В случае с "родными" (русскими или ставшими привычнми) топонимами затруднения чисто фонетические, язык всегда найдёт способ их обойти.

Comment: >Ни в одном словаре нет слов воронежка, воронежанка, воронежчанка (в то время как запорожанка есть).  
   
А что не нравиттся в воронежке? По сути, без ссылок на снобизм составительей словарей.   
Вот наличие нормативности у воронежки пождтрверждает довольно авторитетный источник.  
http://www.rg.ru/2012/05/10/govorim.html   
Кстати, там можно найти и предположительную причину нелюбви словарей к воронежке. Просто не привыкли, ибо раньше бвли аоронежанк и воронежанки. О чем, кстати, сами воронежцы не забыли.

Answer (score -2):

Скорее всего, это -- *запорожица*.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?